# My php echo row['Date'] somehow just disappears

Tags: php, mysql

It is just a very simple:

```
<td>Created Date:</td><td><?php echo $row2['CreatedDate']; ?></td>
```

however it works in one page for a mysql table with the same field name and same data type datetime, but in another page for with exactly same field and datatime type in another table, the text just disappears. 
I try:

```
$test = date_format($row2['CreatedDate'], 'g:i A');
    echo $test; ?></td>
```

then I get this error:

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, null given in
>   So somehow it is null.

Any idea?

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Well, the error message is crystal clear, isn't it? Function `date_format()` expects an argument of type `DateTime`, but you hand over `NULL` which is aparently the value of `$row2`. So what _are_ the values in `$row`?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$date = date_create($row2['CreatedDate']);
echo date_format($date,"g:i A");
```

Comment: It returns the current time and day instead of the datetime of that field in database

Comment: because $row2['CreatedDate'] returns null value, please check the value in database